# XCode with Single View Application (MonoDevelop) Fails Build - Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

On the MonoTouch cruise ship wet behind the ears.

Steps I followed the Hellow World tut from the Xamarin site; http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/hello_iphone

1) Installed XCode via App Store

2) Installed MonoDevelop fresh from the Xamarin site

Created new project "HelloApple" (Single View Application) in MonoDevelop.

Built the app (command+B).

Opened the generated HelloApple_UIViewController.xib file with XCode Interface Builder

Clicked the Run button.

**Received the following error;**

> Ld
>   DerivedData/HelloApple.UI/Build/Products/MonoTouch-iphonesimulator/HelloApple.UI.app/HelloApple.UI
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/randerson/Projects/HelloApple/HelloApple.UI/obj/Xcode/1
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/MonoDevelop.app:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/randerson/Projects/HelloApple/HelloApple.UI/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/HelloApple.UI/Build/Products/MonoTouch-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/randerson/Projects/HelloApple/HelloApple.UI/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/HelloApple.UI/Build/Products/MonoTouch-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/randerson/Projects/HelloApple/HelloApple.UI/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/HelloApple.UI/Build/Intermediates/HelloApple.UI.build/MonoTouch-iphonesimulator/HelloApple.UI.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelloApple.UI.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework UIKit -framework MapKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/randerson/Projects/HelloApple/HelloApple.UI/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/HelloApple.UI/Build/Products/MonoTouch-iphonesimulator/HelloApple.UI.app/HelloApple.UI
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_main", referenced from:
>         start in crt1.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I have uninstalled XCode and MonoDevelop thinking I did things out of order or something a few times.
Really stumped. I would think the example would work out the box, so I gotta be missing something here.
Several posts on StackOverflow revolve around more complex already built apps, this is adding nothing to the project right out of the box and build.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like nothing is being compiled into objective c. or at least all of the h files that come into XCode are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not build from Xcode itself, you build from MonoDevelop.

The most commonly used part of Xcode is the **Interface Builder**. You can create your UI using this tool (or using code) and then save it to disk. You then switch back to MonoDevelop to compile verything into a native application.

Note: MonoTouch itself will use parts of Xcode (command line tools) to build the native application. However, for most developers, this is not something you'll be aware of.